# Google Cloud Firestore, Swift/XCode, Creating Index Through Error Message - URL Now Missing From Error Message

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an IOS App using XCode / Swift, and Google Cloud Firestore. I will typically create new Firestore indexes by writing the Swift/Firestore code, hit the error that says "this query requires an index...click the link to create the index", and then I will follow the link to create the index via the Firebase Console.

Recently, in my development environment, I deleted several existing Firestore indexes, made some changes to the code, and then attempted to run the app. I expect the error "this query requires an index...", but I'm getting a new error that just says "no matching index found.", without the helpful link to create the index. This new error is showing up for indexes related to code that was modified, as well as for indexes related to code that I did not modify (where indexes were previously working fine).

I cannot find any documentation about what to do when the error message does not prompt to create the index, and I prefer to not create these indexes by hand through the console. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
func dummyListener(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) -> ListenerRegistration? {
    let user_id = "12345"
    
    let listener = db.collection("some_collection")
        .order(by: "created_time")
        .whereField("some_object.user_id", isEqualTo: user_id)
        .addSnapshotListener {(snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
             //Throws "no matching index found" error
             //Expect "this query requires an index..." url
                return completion(err)
            }
            //...
        }
    return listener
}
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#index_building_errors

Comment: Thanks @ElTomato. I can't find a place to identify whether I've exceed my index quota. If I did exceed the quota and that is what is causing the error - shouldn't it reset at 12am Pacific?

Comment: Same problem here, no url coming up, just this simple error message. Worked until yesterday, furthermore I can create composite queries manually via Firestore UI (although they don't really work because I probably didn't configure them correctly).

Comment: @Kheber I verified that I'm not exceeding an indexing quota, and was blocked on this. We resorted to manually creating the indexes, with good results. good luck